# Finding the client ID of dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clientid

How can I find the client ID of a dynamically created control?

In my ascx, I have the following snippet.

```
  function DoSomething() {
        var loneStar= $find("<%= loneStar.ClientID %>");
        loneStar.hide();
    }
```

In my code behind, I have

```
public partial class SomeControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    protected Label loneStar = new Label { Text = "Raspeberry", ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray};

    private void someOtherMethod()
         {
         somePanel.Controls.Add(loneStar);
         }
    }
```

The problem is that the ClientID in the rendered page comes up as empty.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give the control an ID, otherwise no ID attribute will be generated.  Make a change to your c# that looks something like this:

```
protected Label loneStar = new Label { ID = "loneStar", Text = "Raspeberry", ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray};
```

Comment: +1 Ender.  While `<%= loneStar.ClientID %>` will render the generated `ID` of the control, the actual rendered `<span>` will not have an `ID` attribute unless one is explicitly specified.

Comment: Yeah, actually Town is correct. The clientID generated just turns out to be the ID specified, not what I was expecting, like a ctl_xxx. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look into NamingContainer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx.  The naming container heirarchy is what creates the IDs you are referring to.  However, if you are dynamically creating controls, .NET leaves it up to you to ensure that they are unique.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

http://jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var txtUsernameID = '<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>';
   var txtPasswordID = '<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>';
 </script>
```

Maybe you should check, if you are adding dynamically the control each time with the same id

Simple Form:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl"></asp:Panel>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txtUsernameID = '<%= myLabel.ClientID %>';
```

CodeBehind :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddedControl();
    }

    protected Label myLabel = new Label();
    void AddedControl()
    {
        myLabel.Text = "Labelll";
        this.pnl.Controls.Add(myLabel);
    }
}
```

Html Output:

```
<span>Labelll</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtUsernameID = 'ctl02';
```

Comment: I don't mean to be snarky, but did you read the question?  OP clearly has that snippet already.

Comment: ok downvotes fair enough but i just tried what OP did and i can get clientID of dynamically added Label

Comment: You have probably explicitly set an ID for your elements, whereas OP did not.

Comment: @adt: See my comment on Ender's answer - the `ClientID` _will_ be dynamically generated, but it won't exist on the DOM element as an `ID` attribute so `$find()` won't work.

Comment: fair enough ,  i checked html again and yes it has and id generated on server side, but span has no id attribute.